# Nested loops work too slow in Python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, optimization, nested-loops

Just figured out that 2 nested loops work extremely slow in Python. CPU load stays around 0% but it still works slow. Why? How can I fix that?

Initialization (shouldn't comment it to make it work fast):

```
    a = imresize(image, (maxY, maxX), 'lanczos')
    b = imresize(image, (maxY * 2, maxX), 'lanczos')
```

Slow code:

```
    result = np.empty((maxY, maxX, 3), dtype=np.uint16)
    for y in range(maxY):
        for x in range(maxX):
            result[y, x] = [a[y, x], a[y, x], a[y, x]]
```

And this one works even more slow:

```
    result = np.empty((maxY, maxX, 3), dtype=np.uint16)
    for y in range(maxY):
        for x in range(maxX):
            result[y, x] = [a[y, x], b[y*2, x], b[y*2+1, x]]
```

Is there any other more effective code to achieve the same results?

Shape of a is (299, 299), b - (598, 299), result - (299, 299, 3). I call the code about 5000 times (and wait about 10 minutes for that amount of data).

If I comment the provided code everything works **just a second**.

Comment: 1) fix your algorithm, 2) use numpy 3) use CPython are all options. Without more info, it's hard to say anything

Comment: No info about any of those variables or your cpu-load evaluation is given...

Comment: Always, *always*, **always** use NumPy when your doing operations on every element of an array.

Comment: Show a more complete code (definition and shapes of all those vars) and tell us how you measured cpu-load.

Comment: Measured CPU load using Task Manager in Windows 10.

Comment: @o11c, how can I achieve the same results using NumPy?

Comment: You said you have arrays of uint8, but did not use numpy already. That does not make much sense (in most cases).

Comment: I've just added `result` variable initialization code.

Comment: The most strange thing is CPU load around 0%... How is it even possible?

Comment: Using python for-loops on `numpy` data-structures will likely be *slower* than the equivalent loop over vanilla Python lists...

Comment: You still did not present those shapes / sizes. Yeah, in most cases this behaviour makes no sense. Let's trust you and assume a and b are random-access types (and not slow over-full dicts): the only possible reason imho is trashing because your memory is full.

Comment: Shape of a is (299, 299), b - (598, 299), result - (299, 299, 3). I call the code about 5000 times (and wait about 10 minutes for that amount of data). I have 64 GB DRAM and use up to 8 GB total. CPU has 8/16 cores, 4.3 GHz each.

Comment: Those shapes make no sense. This will result in out of bounds with ```y*2``` (you did not supress all kinds of error with exception-handling from the outside i hope; exceptions for example are slow). Let's be serious: without a much much more complete code, there will be no help. It's very much possible, that the problem is not within the code above. **Edit** he edited his shapes.

Comment: Fixed, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: I can assure you that the problem is with the provided code. If I comment it everything works **just a second**.

Comment: That's the wrong logic. But, well, your decision.

Comment: That's 100% **complete code** that makes the program work slow if I uncomment it.

Comment: Very complete, without seing ```a``` and ```b```, ```maxY``` (yeah, you implicitly defined the latter; but well...) and co. Don't bother...

Comment: I shouldn't comment `a, b` initialization to make it work just a second! `a = imresize(image, (maxY, maxX), 'lanczos'), b = imresize(image, (maxY * 2, maxX), 'lanczos')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please use vectorization to fix your code.
like that:

```
result[:,:,0] = a
```

Comment: Nice idea! But I still have to use one loop with it.

Answer (score 2):

Allocating memory is always slow in every language, so you need to avoid it. In your example, you create a `list` in every loop.

You should use something like the following:

```
result = np.empty((maxY, maxX, 3), dtype=np.uint16)
for y in range(maxY):
    for x in range(maxX):
        result[y, x, 0] = a[y, x]
        result[y, x, 1] = a[y, x]
        result[y, x, 2] = a[y, x]
```

Or as mentioned by @user3237718, you should use:

```
result = np.empty((maxY, maxX, 3), dtype=np.uint16)
for i in range(3):
    result[:, :, i] = a
```

The key point is to avoid dynamically allocating memory.

Comment: Already tried the first version of the code myself. It helped only a little.

Comment: @Dmitry Try the second one, it helps a lot.